# Что означает $this->$param и как это работает?

Tags: php, this

На ютубе человек использует $ после $this, но в интернете об этом не нашёл (это не орфографическа ошибка)

Comment: коротко $param содержит имя свойства или метода

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 1):

`$param` содержит в себе названия параметра класса или метода. Например:

```php
$param = "myFunction";
$this->$param();
```

То же самое, если:

```php
$this->myFunction();
```

Answer (score -1):

Как я понял: это как $$object, но в виде объекта